# Stub helper function in chefspec

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, stub

Searched all day and haven't solved this, so here goes. **EDIT: the process of writing this post forced me to think about the problem differently, and I figured it out. So I'll answer my own question here. I think I checked "answer your own question".**

I have a line in recipe `web.rb` that calls a helper function:

```
  prodservice_machine_name = search_for_nodes("ProdApp_Service_Install:1 AND chef_environment:#{node_env}")[0]['fqdn']
```

`search_for_nodes` is defined in `spec_helpers.rb`, wraps some help around a `knife` search, and returns `nodes[]`

We use the response to find a node's machine name:

```
prodservice_machine_name = search_for_nodes("ProdApp_Service_Install:1 AND chef_environment:#{node_env}")[0]['fqdn']
```

I couldn't figure out how to stub `search_for_nodes` to get a usable response.

Comment: I'm glad you figured this one out! Standard procedure would be to not put your answer in the question, but to post it as an answer.

Comment: I thought I'd checked `Answer Your Own Question` when i posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said above I was writing this question up, and the act of writing the question made it dawn on me what the issue was: I wasn't mocking the return in the correct format, a key-value array.

I finally came up with this:

```
before(:each) do
  receive(:search_for_nodes).and_return(['fqdn' => 'dummy_server'])
end
```

It works, and I can test that my recipe correctly uses `dummy_server` in the right place.